# Docker - Redirect output in entrypoint

Tags: docker

I have a Dockerfile where I'm trying to redirect input from a Java file. My Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM docker.repo1.acme.com/eaip/jdk11-alpine-docker-slim:latest

LABEL maintainer="Data Externalization Team"

COPY entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod 777 /entrypoint.sh

COPY /build/libs/provider-selection-mapper-java.jar /app.jar

ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]
```

My entrypoint.sh file looks like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec java -jar /app.jar </pipes/in >/pipes/out 2>/pipes/err
```

After building the container and trying to run it with `docker run -it provider-selection-mapper-java`, I get `/entrypoint.sh: line 2: can't open /pipes/in: no such file`

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What's in the file `/pipes/in`?  Does the `/pipes` directory exist at all?

Comment: If I sh into the container, the `/pipes` directory does exist. `/pipes/in` is empty.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the above does work. I had an issue somewhere else in my app that was misleading me to believe I had an issue with Docker, but the above code using the entrypoint.sh file does the trick.